# Editing a Excel template with POI in Netbeans

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, apache-poi

I have a Excel template wich I want to open, modify and save it like a normal book of excel when I click in a button in a Jframe.

This is the code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    InputStream inp;
    try {
        inp = new FileInputStream("plantilla.xlt");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(1);
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(3);
        XSSFCell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
        XSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(2);
         
        cell1.setCellValue(0);
        cell2.setCellValue(10000);

        //FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("plantilla.xlt");
        //wb.write(fileOut);
        //fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Logger.getLogger(DonnéesFE.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ioe);
    }

}
```

This is new for me so I have a couple questions:

1. I have to put the whole file path to get the `FileInputStream`? Is the extension `.xlt` correct? Right now it doesn't find the file. I have tried with the normal `.xlsx` extension and it finds it (I don't think it found the good file either) but I get this error on the definition of the workbook that I don't understand:

   > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException.`
2. When I finish editing the excel template how I save it as a new excel book? Everybody uses a new file to save the output but I think that won't work here.

Comment: Did you check https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html? I would generate a "blank" from the template and use that as "base workbook"

Comment: Error #1 is fairly clear - you're missing at least one of the Apache POI dependencies. Have another review of the [Apache POI components and dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) and add in the ones you forgot!

Comment: @Gagravarr if I have the import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;should work no? I dont know what else import!

Comment: You don't need to *import* anything, you need to ensure that all the required *jar* files are present

Comment: @RC. I have checked the guide but didnt found anything clear, the "blank" generated from the template would have all the characteristics of the template?

Comment: @Gagravarr Ok, I have the jar file: poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208. The thing I dont get its why it doesnt give me any error before I run it, if the problem is that I dont have the requested jar files present, shouldnt it give me an error, of cannot find symbol for example, before runing it?

Comment: @IgnacioMtzDeSalinasUreta except it will not be a template (regarding excel) anymore